# Meaning of infinity sign in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I searched extensively and can't figure out what the infinity sign is meant in this pseudocode. [image]

The code is taken from [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/CSG713.06F/Information/Handouts/dyn_prog.pdf), which has a detailed explanation of dynamic programming for the coin change problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969500/what-are-sentinel-in-c-language-i-was-learning-merge-sort-and-came-across-using

Comment: A useful property of infinity is that x < infinity for any real x. See answers in linked question.

Comment: Please, post code. Not pictures of code. This is a site for software engineers, not photographers or painters. We want to copy&paste your code, not critique its use of color and perspective.

Comment: "I searched extensively and cant figure out what the infinity sign is meant in this pseudocode." – It means "infinity".

Comment: It means infinity...

Answer (score 8):

That line (3) is simply saying initialize the Minimum value to the highest feasible value. In pseudocode that is infinity. If min was UInt32 in real code, then min would be UInt32.Max.

In other words, start off min at a really high value, so when searching iteratively for progressively lower values (by comparing to the previous value), then the first value is something so high that the next value will always become the next min.